# C# server respond to socket.io

Tags: c#, socket.io

I currently am working on a new project which will contain of a client in JavaScript with `socket.io` and a server in `C#.`

However, I have no clue how to respond to the data sent when I connect my client to the server.

In my JavaScript I have:

```
var socket = io('http://127.0.0.1:30000');
```

And I have `SocketTest` open and a server started on port 30000. SocketTest will receive the following data:

```
GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MDMuIkH HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:30000
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
Origin: http://127.0.0.1:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36
Referer: http://127.0.0.1:8080/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: nl-NL,nl;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Cookie: SOME COOKIE DATA
```

What do I correctly send back to the client with this?

Comment: There may not be one which is fully compatible with Socket.IO, but see https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/598281/SocketIO-Programming-in-Csharp-using-SocketIO-Net and  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/socket_io/KPv7-q-N-ig,

Answer (score 2):

Take a look here: [C# Server Socket Program](http://csharp.net-informations.com/communications/csharp-server-socket.htm)

You have to do networkStream.Read and networkStream.Write and whatever you decide to write back, you just need to interpret correctly on the JavaScript side.
However
I suggest you take a look at JSON and maybe the following site because you are doing things that have been done for you already. [Posting URL-encoded key values with HttpClient](http://ronaldrosiernet.azurewebsites.net/Blog/2013/12/07/posting_urlencoded_key_values_with_httpclient)

Answer (score 0):

The server is connected to the Port 30000, so you need to reads data from NetworkStream , and also write to the NetworkStream .